# Cannot see SSIDs except for mobile hotspots, why?

Tags: wi-fi

I have no idea why, but I cannot see any of the SSIDs, except for mobile hotspots from phones or laptops. I am from Belgium and am in the USA now, if that matters. Someone told me, it's because I can only see 802.11n networks and they are probably broadcasting 802.11 b/g, not n. Am i really not able to connect? Or can I change my settings somewhere to find those networks. This is really inconvenient :/

Edit: Could it be related to the channel it is sending out? Are they sending over different channels in the USA and Europe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems they were broadcasting in 5GHz only, which my phone cannot receive...